# WCF Rest Service Return HttpWebResponse

Tags: wcf, rest

I am creating a WCF Rest service that calls another web service.  The desired outcome is for my web service to return untouched the HttpWebResponse that comes from the other web service.  Something like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "DoSomething?variable={variable}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    HttpWebResponse DoSomething(string variable);  

public HttpWebResponse DoSomething(string variable)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(otherServicerequestUrl);
    return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I guess no. But you can try to use System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class. In SOAP serivces it is used exactly for this purpose but I have no idea if it works with REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the new WCF Http stack at wcf.codeplex.com.  At the moment you can do something similar, in a future release they are planning something to address exactly what you want to do.

You can currently do the following with the WCF Http stack.

```
public void DoSomething(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own routing service.
Create an interface for routing service with contract all ("*")

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRoutingService
{

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")]
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true, Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
    IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(Message requestMessage, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState);

    Message EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult);

}
```

Then implement this in service

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
    AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class RoutingService : IRoutingService, IDisposable
    {
        private IRoutingService _client;

        public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(Message requestMessage, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState)
        {

            ClientSection clientSection = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
            string clientEndPoint = clientSection.Endpoints[0].Address.AbsoluteUri;
            string methodCall = requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsolutePath.Substring(requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsolutePath.IndexOf(".svc") + 4);

            Uri uri = new Uri(clientEndPoint + "/" + methodCall);
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri);
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding("JsonBinding");
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IRoutingService>(binding, endpointAddress);

            // Set message address
            requestMessage.Headers.To = factory.Endpoint.Address.Uri;

            // Create client channel
            _client = factory.CreateChannel();

            // Begin request
            return _client.BeginProcessRequest(requestMessage, asyncCallback, asyncState);
        }

        public Message EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Message message = null;
            try
            {
                message = _client.EndProcessRequest(asyncResult);
            }
            catch(FaultException faultEx)
            {
                throw faultEx;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ServiceData myServiceData = new ServiceData();
                myServiceData.Result = false;
                myServiceData.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                myServiceData.ErrorDetails = ex.Message;
                throw new FaultException<ServiceData>(myServiceData, ex.Message);
            }
            return message;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        if (_client != null)
            {
                var channel = (IClientChannel)_client;
                if (channel.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        channel.Close();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        channel.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and do configuration in web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="RoutingService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonRoutingBehave">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IRoutingService" name="serviceName" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<client>
  <endpoint address="<actual service url here>" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration ="JsonBinding" contract="*" name="endpointName">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"
                automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                faultExceptionEnabled="true"/>
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JsonRoutingBehave">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <routing filterTableName="ftable"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<routing>
  <filters>
    <filter name="all" filterType="MatchAll"/>
  </filters>

  <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="ftable">
      <add filterName="all" endpointName="endpointName"/>
    </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
</routing>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="JsonBinding" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```